# How do I pass login information to a website from UIWebView directly without any need of logging in once again?

Tags: iphone, authentication, uiwebview, autologin

I want to open some website in my iphone app using UIWebView. The website requires username and password and I have these username and password.

I was wondering is there anyway I can open the website in my UIWebView without any login screen? I mean as I already have the username and password, can I use this information to log in to website automatically and show the required necessary page onto my UIWebView iphone app.

I just want to get rid of logging to website as users have already entered the login information when they open the app. Thats redundant.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have discovered way to solve this in a Objective-C way. We can use NSURLConnection to post the form.

Code:

```
 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest=[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://mobile.twitter.com/session"]
                                                 cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy                                              timeoutInterval:60.0];

[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *postString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"authenticity_token=%@&username=%@&password=%@",@"9b670208fd22850ec791",@"urUsername",@"urPWD"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody:[postString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

// create the connection with the request
// and start loading the data
NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];
if (theConnection) {
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // Inform the user that the connection failed.
}
```

Ask me if you need more information.

Comment: isn't it a problem that the username and pass are going back and forth to the server? isn't it really easy to hack to catch these?

Comment: Yeah, I realized it can be a security problem. So do you have any idea in how I can do this in a better way ?

Comment: This is how a browser would send the request anyway, so standard security practices apply. Use digest auth or ssl the entire connection.

Comment: Matt, can you tell me how can I store the session/cookie or save the state of the connection for this request, so that I do not need to login to web site each time I want to access the page.

Comment: Is there server side code required for this, or is it all on the native app side?

Answer (score 0):

If you have developed the website yourself, why not create another entry point where you pass the username/password securely, using ssl, to the page?  If SSL is not an options, you could generate a token within the app and pass this.  No need for username/password to be passed at all then.

Comment: Well website is not developed by us, its my customers websites. So this website changes from customer to customer.

Comment: Ok, if customer won't create a separate "app entry page" then what I have done in the past is to create a form with the same elements, named in the same way and pre-populate the data, then submit the form automatically.

Be careful to include all hidden form elements, and other items needed when the form is submitted.

Comment: Yeah, I created the login form in UIWebView and submitted a post request and it worked. But I am wondering is there a way where I can create Sessions and just send the session to the website. please advice.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by create sessions and send them to the website? I assume you mean create the server session and push it to the web server - if so, i'm not sure you can do this for security reasons. Why not make all form elements hidden and have the form autosubmit onload? The user wouldn't even see the form, or have to click on a submit button.

Comment: Yeah, what you said works absolutely fine. Thanks for the info.

Comment: I have asked my customers to create separate app entry point. But my question is how do I create a token in ios and how do I send it to that website.  Looks like creating a token inside the app is the best way to do it, really appreciate it if you can give me more info on that.