# IOS: Passing session credentials between app and website

Tags: ios, iphone

I am doing an IOS application that has a UIWebview. The user login in the IOS side that passing from PHP api and after login have UIWebView that use same credentials. I would like to keep the user login without asking him the credentials.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: maybe you have to write web service for that because your php site uses session for every action on website.

Comment: please check this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5505707/how-do-i-pass-login-information-to-a-website-from-uiwebview-directly-without-any

this helps you.

Comment: pass credentials to web page and assign it to fields with javascript and call event manually for submition.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can store the credentials in key chain and in webview you can use javascript to identify elements (textfields) and populate values accordingly

Comment: do you know any tutorial how to do it?